# Can't connect to cloudpool elasticserach

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

I wanted to give a elastic cloud a try today, but I can't seem to connect from c# app. Everything is working fine with locally deployed version but with cloud I'm always getting this error.
I deployed it to azure (free trial thing).
NEST client version is 7.14
.net 5.0
Error:
The client is unable to verify that the server is Elasticsearch due to an unsuccessful product check call. Some functionality may not be compatible if the server is running an unsupported product
Error2:
Authentication failed because the remote party sent a TLS alert: 'HandshakeFailure'.

this is how I'm setting up client

```
            var cloudId = "cloudid:xxxxxxxx";
            var credentials = new BasicAuthenticationCredentials("elastic", "xxxxxxxxxxxx");
            var pool = new CloudConnectionPool(cloudId, credentials);
            var settings = new ConnectionSettings(pool)
                .ThrowExceptions()
                .EnableDebugMode();

            var client = new ElasticClient(settings);
```

Looks like an issue with OS, as I'm using Windows 11 Preview as same code is working on Ubuntu 20.04 and Windows server.

Comment: What version of elasticsearch are you running?

Comment: @Rob Hello, it's 7.14.